# How make permission for change attribute in Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

*For example:* we have the model **Profile**. Each user profile has attribute `alias_name` that can be set only once (*when you create*), and can not be changed (*when you update*).

Of course I can override action `.update()` in the controller and remove the attribute from `req.body`. But then lost all the magic Blueprint API.

More I can create special policies that will remove the attribute from `req.body`. But not sure it's right.

Perhaps it should be made in the method `.beforeUpdate()` in the Profile model?

How better to do? Share your experiences?

Comment: I'm working on a permissions framework for sails: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions. It's currently not complete, but I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use approach with [custom validation rule](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Validations.html?q=custom-validation-rules) for this attribute

```
// /api/models/profile.js

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        alias_name: {
            type: 'string',
            nonEditable: true
        }
    },
//  ...
    types: {
        nonEditable: function(prop) {
            return prop === null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, this fields can be changed only once (in case you have not `defaultsTo` specified for `alias_name`).

Comment: Thank you so much.
I think this is the right decision.